# Pod Headers Can't be Found/LibPods.a Missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

After pulling the changes a friend made to a repo, I get a build error related to CocoaPods.

I believe the problem is that there's no/Xcode can't find libPods.a. But you tell me... here's some screenshots that might help:

**Original error** (note that if I comment out Mixpanel, the error then occurs for the next item, Parse. If I comment out Parse, it occurs for the next item, etc. all the way down to the white space):
[image: note that if I comment out Mixpanel, the error then occurs for the next item, Parse. If I comment out Parse, it occurs for the next item, etc. all the way down to the white space]

**libPods.a Missing**
[image: test image description here]

**Other**
Admittedly I don't know if these are helpful, but they seem relevant (e.g. Framework Search Paths).
[image]
[image]

Things I have tried:

1. Verifying I'm opening .xcworkspace and NOT .xcodeproj
2. Reinstalling Cocoapods (sudo gem install cocoapods)
3. Delete .xcworkspace, Podfile.lock, and Pods folder, and run `pod install` again.

Comment: Try removing .xcworkspace, Podfile.lock and Pods folder and run `pod install`again. Regarding the libPods.a file it't usually missing until you build the project.

Comment: Just tried this, but still no luck.

Comment: Try look at the project (not target) and look under Info->Configurations check that you have configurations set for the scheme and target you are building. Maybe those are missing?

Comment: That worked! Now it's telling me it can't find the file "Pods-resources.sh" in the Pods folder.

Comment: It's building successfully now. If you add your 2nd comment as an answer I'll mark it correct

Comment: what's the solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try look at the project and look under Info->Configurations check that you have configurations set for the scheme and target you are building.

Comment: I cant find configurations option in the info field please help!

Comment: Make sure you select the "project" not the "target"